# C# Application with SQL Server install

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, installation, sql-server-2008-express

I am trying to install my C# application on a VMWare machine with Windows Vista, the PC is completely clean. The install works fine except for the last part, when SQL Server 2008 Express is trying to install, after that, a batch, converted to an .exe will be fired, to create the database. At that moment it says it is getting an error, I made this installer with setup and deployment in my C# application. I don't know if there is any way to see what I did wrong, so maybe one of you guys know..

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

This is the code I'am executing at the end of the install it is executed by an .exe
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -i "script.sql"

Comment: Can show the error message you are receiving? Check the event logs if it is not directly shown.

Comment: Could you share the error?

Comment: I don't know how I can see the error log, but it gives me the error that the installation failed, right after executing the .exe for the build of the database.

Comment: Is your install an MSI? You can use msiexec to run the installer with verbose logging on (run with -? to get the command line flags, I always mix them up)

Comment: Is the installation it working on the computer (not on VM)? Are any objects created in the SQL Server?

Comment: No, I can't test it without VM, because I am developing on my notebook, which already has sql express 2008 and 2012. And it needs to be installed on a clean pc

Comment: Is it your app that is creating the database (the batch turned into an exe)...why not update your exe to write a log file?

Comment: No, it is the setup, that triggers a simple line of code

Comment: sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -i "script.sql" this code is is triggerd at the end of my installation